# JSF: ui:include does not work with ui:define

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have a set of edit.xhtml pages, each with a related managed bean `manager`, a common subset of defines, and a subset of varying defines. I want to encapsulate the common defines thus, but it fails (the `manager` ui:param is not passed in):

From a typical `edit.xtml`:

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">

        <ui:include src="/include/define_common_edit.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="manager" value="#{quantityManager}"/>
        </ui:include>

<ui:define name="body">
   // specific part
```

Where `define_common_edit.xhtml` is:

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"        
    xmlns:util="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/util">

    <ui:define name="htmltitle">
        <util:edit_htmltitle manager="#{manager}"/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="title">
        <util:edit_title manager="#{manager}"/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="actions">
        <util:edit_actions manager="#{manager}"/>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Q: Why doesn't `ui:include` handle `ui:define` in such cases (i.e. why doesn't the `ui:include` "work first" before `ui:define` is interpreted) ?

An acceptable answer will not simply explain how `ui:include` and `ui:define` work, I know that already. The answer must be in terms of the JSF spec. or a similar authoritative description (I've examined the JSF spec and Java EE tutorials but did not yet find an exact description covering the situation described above).

*Suggestions for how I might otherwise encapsulate that non-varying group of `ui:define` elements above to promote [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) coding are welcome.*